# Get alignment of a type in Linux

Tags: c, linux, alignment

Is there a system call/library function to get alignment of a type (e. g. int or double) in Linux?
Also can I get the minimum alignment that suffices all types?

Answer (score 0):

The C11 standard introduces the [`_Alignof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof), and the convenience macro `alignof`.

Also, GCC has had the [`__alignof__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alignment.html) keyword for a while.